# avoiding multiple attemps to mysql_connect

Tags: php

File : Config.php

```
<?php
    require 'inc.database.php';
    // Checking if there already a connection. If not then connect to the database.
    if(!$IsConnected){
        $Database = new Database();
        $Database->connect("localhost", "aih786_raheel", "raheel786",        "aih786_basicblog");
        $IsConnected = TRUE;
    }
    ?>
```

I m using my config file on my every page because on every page i need to have my database object. Thing i want to clear is that by this approach can i avoid multiple attemps to connect to the database as it is not a good practice to make same connection again and again.

Lets say i have a login page which is the first page of my cms. The connection will be opened on the login page and now when i move to the dashboard.php page i require the config.php file in this page too...so by this it won't create the connection and object again.

Pleas tell me is this the right approach to achieve my goal and also will it give me the access to the object $Database ? I'm not sure if we can use the object on differnt pages once it has been created on first page.

Comment: What is `Database`? Where is it defined? Great job on choosing your password btw.

Comment: it is the class 'inc.database.php' it cosntains connect and crud method.. and for the password lol :P its just dummy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rudimentary approach would be to define a function that returns a database connection on-demand, e.g.:

```
function getDefaultDatabaseConnection()
{
    $db = new Database;
    $db->connect(...);

    return $db;
}
```

Comment: @RameezShah You only call it when you need it.

Comment: so i need the database connection on every page i can use my method too?

Comment: @RameezShah It's not a good design to have global variables floating around; and singletons are bad too, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I try to fire up one connection per page load that needs it.
If I have the proper variable already stored in SESSION variables, then oftentimes
it is not necessary to fire one up.

Given that, I do consider it proper form to drop the connection object at the end 
of the script that called it.

And Jack is right, I use a function to fire up the connection.

```
function dbConnect_readOnly() {

$host="127.0.0.1";
$user="*********";
$password="********";
$dbname="**********";
try {
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
        $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo "Unable to connect to database.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }  
return $DBH;
```

}

and to close:

```
function dbClose_connection($DBH) {
        $DBH = null;
    }
```

Include the script at the top of every page that eeds connectivity just after you check for session variables.